# Is there a way to get the email address associated with a Windows Live ID?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows-live-id

I have a client that wants to use Windows Live ID Delegated Authentication SDK 1.2 to provide authentication for their website.

The architecture that they proposed was to have a database table that contained the email addresses of users who were authorized to use the site.  Once the user logged using Windows Live ID web authentication, they wanted to compare the email address associated with that live ID to the table and allow/disallow the user access to the site based on that.

Is this possible? I can't find any documentation that talks about how to get the email address associated with the Windows Live ID.

Comment: IIRC from the passport days you almost always could get the email from user properties (like as OpenID) unless the user turned it off, in which case you got just got the 64-bit int. No idea if it still works like that, but I don't think there's a way to guarantee it's available.

Comment: Not 100% what you want, but the way to do this with the latest Facebook-graph-like-API, Windows Messenger Connect, is to request "wl.emails" in the login scope parameter. Try [this example](http://isdk.dev.live.com/ISDK.aspx?category=Core+Concepts&index=1) and edit `"wl.basics"` to `"wl.basics, wl.emails"`.

Comment: You could try passing `wl.emails` in the PS parameter for your [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287661.aspx](delegation request). However if you're starting from scratch rather than updating an existing Live ID application you should probably just implement [Messenger Connect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/default.aspx) (the latest version of the API) instead. And here it's just `wl.emails` permission as above. However you could always ask the user for their email when they first log in and send them a verify link, and discover it that way?

Comment: That's an option.  But can't the person with the Live ID deny sending their email to sites?  Only other option is a two step authenticate then register process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was originally looking for the way to do this with the Rest API, but it doesn't seem to work.

Using "wl.basics, wl.emails" solved the problem, albeit I don't have a fallback for when javascript is disabled.

Example from Rup:
http://isdk.dev.live.com/ISDK.aspx?category=Core+Concepts&index=1